# Which objects can I use in a finalizer method?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that should delete some file when disposed or finalized. Inside finalizers I can't use other objects because they could have been garbage-collected already.

Am I missing some point regarding finalizers and strings could be used?

UPD: Something like that:

```
public class TempFileStream : FileStream
{
    private string _filename;

    public TempFileStream(string filename)
        :base(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    {
        _filename = filename;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (_filename == null) return;

        try
        {
            File.Delete(_filename); // <-- oops! _filename could be gc-ed already
            _filename = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing is garbage collected when its used or could be used, not even in finalizers.

Comment: No, @Dani is in fact correct. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can most certainly use strings from within a finalizer, and many other object types.

For the definitive source of all this, I would go pick up the book [CLR via C#, 3rd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045), written by Jeffrey Richter. In chapter 21 this is all described in detail.

Anyway, here's what is really happening...

During garbage collection, any objects that have a finalizer that still wants to be called are placed on a special list, called the *freachable* list.

This list is considered a root, just as static variables and live local variables are. Therefore, any objects *those* objects refer to, and so on recursively is removed from the garbage collection cycle this time. **They will survive the current garbage collection cycle as though they weren't eligible to collect to begin with.**

**Note that this includes strings, which was your question, but it also involves *all* other object types**

Then, at some later point in time, the finalizer thread picks up the object from that list, and runs the finalizer on those objects, and then takes those objects off that list.

Then, the next time garbage collection runs, it finds the same objects once more, but this time the finalizer no longer wants to run, it has already been executed, and so the objects are collected as normal.

Let me illustrate with an example before I tell you what doesn't work.

Let's say you have objects A through Z, and each object references the next one, so you have object A referencing object B, B references C, C references D, and so on until Z.

Some of these objects implement finalizers, and they all implement IDisposable. Let's assume that A does not implement a finalizer but B does, and then some of the rest does as well, it's not important for this example which does beyond A and B.

Your program holds onto a reference to A, and only A.

In an ordinary, and correct, usage pattern you would dispose of A, which would dispose of B, which would dispose of C, etc. but you have a bug, so this doesn't happen. At some point, all of these objects are eligible for collection.

At this point GC will find all of these objects, but then notice that B has a finalizer, and it has not yet run. GC will therefore put B on the *freachable* list, and recursively take C, D, E, etc. up to Z, off of the GC list, because since B suddenly became *in-* eligible for collection, so does the rest. Note that some of these objects are also placed on the *freachable* list themselves, because they have finalizers on their own, but *all* the objects they refer to will survive GC.

A, however, is collected.

Let me make the above paragraph clear. At this point, A has been collected, but B, C, D, etc. up to Z *are still alive as though nothing has happened*. Though *your* code no longer has a reference to any of them, the *freachable* list has.

Then, the finalizer thread runs, and finalizes all of the objects in the *freachable* list, and takes the objects off of the list.

The next time GC is run, those objects are now collected.

So that certainly works, so what is the big bruaha about?

The problem is with the finalizer thread. This thread makes no assumptions about the order in which it should finalize those objects. It doesn't do this because in many cases it would be impossible for it to do so.

As I said above, in an ordinary world you would call dispose on A, which disposes B, which disposes C, etc. If one of these objects is a stream, the object referencing the stream might, in its call to Dispose, say "I'll just go ahead and flush my buffers before disposing the stream." This is perfectly legal and lots of existing code do this.

However, in the finalization thread, this order is no longer used, and thus if the stream was placed on the list before the objects that referenced it, the stream is finalized, and thus closed, before the object referencing it.

In other words, what you cannot do is summarized as follows:

> You can not access any objects your object refer to, that has finalizers, as you have no guarantee that these objects will be in a usable state when your finalizer runs. The *objects* will still be *there*, in memory, and not collected, but they may be closed, terminated, finalized, etc. already.

So, *back to your question*:

> Q. Can I use strings in finalizer method?
>   A. Yes, because strings do not implement a finalizer, and does not rely on other objects that has a finalizer, and will thus be alive and kicking at the time your finalizer runs.

The assumption that made you take the wrong path is the second sentence of the qustion:

> Inside finalizers I can't use other objects because they could have been garbage-collected already.

The correct sentence would be:

> Inside finalizer I can't use other objects that have finalizers, because they could have been finalized already.

---

For an example of something the finalizer would have no way of knowing the order in which to *correctly* finalize two objects, consider two objects that refer to each other and that both have finalizers. The finalizer thread would have to analyze the code to determine in which order they would normally be disposed, which might be a "dance" between the two objects. The finalizer thread does not do this, it just finalizes one before the other, and you have no guarantee which is first.

---

So, is there any time it is *safe* to access objects that also have a finalizer, from my own finalizer?

The only guaranteed safe scenario is when your program/class library/source code owns both objects so that you know that it is.

Before I explain this, **this is not really good programming practices, so you probably shouldn't do it**.

Example:

You have an object, `Cache`, that writes data to a file, this file is never kept open, and is thus only open when the object needs to write data to it.

You have another object, `CacheManager`, that uses the first one, and calls into the first object to give it data to write to the file.

`CacheManager` has a finalizer. The semantics here is that if the manager class is collected, but not disposed, it should delete the caches as it cannot guarantee their state.

However, the filename of the cache object is retrievable from a property of the cache object.

So the question is, do I need to make a copy of that filename into the manager object, to avoid problems during finalization?

Nope, you don't. When the manager is finalized, the cache object is still in memory, as is the filename string it refers to. What you cannot guarantee, however, is that any finalizer on the cache object hasn't already run.

However, in this case, if you *know* that the finalizer of the cache object either doesn't exist, or doesn't touch the file, your manager can read the filename property of the cache object, and delete the file.

However, since you now have a pretty strange dependency going on here, I would certainly advice against it.

Comment: Great Answer. The way I understood it is that finalizers run after GC, but going over that part of the book again it now makes sense that GC runs before and after and only collects after finalizing. That way, resurrection and it's associated problems make sense as well.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. I should re-read Richter's book again, as it seems I've forgotten some things :)

Comment: Indeed a valuable answer, but it would be perfect with a TL;DR at the top. From what I understood, it would be something like "You should avoid calling members of referenced non-primitive objects from the finalizer. Technically, you can safely call members of referenced objects that don't have a finalizer, and don't directly or indirectly make use of objects that have a finalizer. But keep in mind that implementations can evolve, so even if it works at some point, it might become a source of hard-to-debug problems later."

Answer (score 1):

Another point not yet mentioned is that although one might not expect that an object's finalizer would ever run while an object is in use, the finalization mechanism does not ensure that.  Finalizers can be run in an arbitrary unknown threading context; as a consequence, they should either avoid using any types that aren't thread-safe, or should use locking or other means to ensure that they only use things in thread-safe fashion.  Note finalizers should use `Monitor.TryEnter` rather than `Monitor.Enter`, and endeavor to act as gracefully as possible if a lock is unexpectedly held.  Note that since finalizers aren't supposed to run while an object is still in use, the fact that a lock was unexpectedly held will often suggest that a finalizer was run early.  Depending upon the design of the code which uses the lock, it may be possible to have the finalizer set a flag and try again to acquire the lock, and have any other code which uses the lock check after releasing it whether that flag is set and, if so, reregister the object for finalization.

Handling finalization cleanup correctly in all threading scenarios is difficult.  Finalization might not seem complicated, but no convenient automated mechanisms exist by which objects can ensure that finalizers won't run while the objects in question are in use.  Consequently, finalizers have a lot of subtle thread-safety issues.  Code which ignores such issues will "usually" work, but may sometimes fail in difficult-to-diagnose ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the dispose method inside your finalizer and have the file cleanup code in the Dispose method. Along with that you can also pass a boolean to your dispose method that indicates that you are invoking it from the finalizer.

For an excellent reference on the proper usage of Dispose and Fianlizers , read this [Proper use of the IDisposable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)

Comment: I know standard pattern, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Ivan I'm sorry i may have misunderstood you question. Can you post the code which highlights you intent ?